# How to plot graph with calculating average on abscissa in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, average

My data-file is formatted as fallows:

```
100;2.123;4.123
100;2.113;5.213
100;2.544;6.234
100;2.324;4.234
200;2.543;3.123
200;2.543;5.123
...
```

First column is a parameter of a function, second and third are the result of a function. The values of 2nd and 3rd are different for the same values of 1st column, because of other factors, and I want to plot a graph that calculates arithmetic average for all values from 2nd and 3rd column that have the same 1st.

Is there any way gnuplot can do this?

Comment: My guess is that it would be extremely tricky to do in general, though it would be doable with some constraints on the data.  For instance, if each value in the first column always appears four times in sequence.  Do you have any such helpful constraints?  For arbitrary data I would recommend a separate utility for preprocessing.

Comment: Well - in this particular problem: yes. Each value in the 1st column always appear 4 times in sequence.

I'm using excel as a separate utility and I'm not pleased with this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate the arithmetic average of all values which share the same 1st value, you can use `smooth unique`. To get the average of all values of the 2nd and 3rd column for the same abscissa, you can use

```
set datafile separator ';'
plot 'datafile' using 1:(($2+$3)/2.0) smooth unique
```

That makes the data monotonic in the `x`-values and then replaces all points with the same abscissa with one point having the averaged `y`-value.

If e.g. you want only the averaged values of the 2nd columns, you would instead use

```
plot 'datafile' using 1:2 smooth unique
```

Comment: You misunderstood my problem (or, more probably, I didn't explaint clear enough). 

I don't want the average of 2.123 and 4.123 but average of 2.123, 2.113, 2.544 and 2.324 = 2,276 and plot with 100, and 4.123, 5.213, 6.234, 4.234 = 4.951 and also plot this with 100 (as different series on plot).

edit: use of the second solution does not give me proper plot - I think the values from 2nd column are summed and plotted with 100.

Comment: If you want the 2nd and the 3rd columns to belong to different series, you can use `plot 'datafile' using 1:2  smooth unique, '' using 1:3 smooth unique`. Or do you want to draw some connections between the two series?

Comment: Oh, I think that works just fine ;) Thanks! Just 2 quick questions: 1. Is there any way to add deviation on every value? 2. I'm using 1:2:xtic(1) fot X-axis to show only values from datafile, but how can I show them evenly distributed?

Comment: Use e.g. `with errorbars` to add deviations. These values are also subject to the smoothing. Regarding the `x`-axis: in your case, with always four same `x`-values, you can use `plot 'datafile' using (int(floor($0/4.0))):2:xtic(1) smooth unique`, or with the errorbars e.g. `plot 'datafile' using (int(floor($0/4.0))):2:(1):xtic(1) smooth unique with errorbars`. But thats almost a new question.

Answer (score 0):

yes !
First of all replace each ; by a blank then
try this command

```
plot "your_data_file" using ($1):(($2+$3)/2)
```

Comment: Rather than change the format of the file, one can use the command `set datafile separator ";"`.